# Using jQuery Validation and callbacks

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-validate

With my code below I am validating the register form on my client side validation and submitting the form with a post method to my php page and returning a json object for my jquery to handle. As you can see I have set up some rules and messages for the initial validation to handle on the client side. On the php side I have it reporting back a status of the request, a message to the user, and any errors that might be present. What I want to know is how should I handle it if there are errors and I want my form to display the errors back to the user in the same exact way that that the user should have seen them in the case it got skipped.

What I would like to see happen is for as the example error messages exist from my json object have it see that its attached to the respective field names and apply the same class with the message somehow.

My output array looks like this:

```
{
    "status":"error",
    "message":"The following form did not validate successfully. Please fix the form errors and try again.",
    "errors":
    {
        "username":"This username is already available",
        "email_address":"This email address is already available"
    }
}
```

Jquery Validation

```
$.validator.setDefaults(
{
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); },
    showErrors: function(map, list) 
    {
        this.currentElements.parents('label:first, div:first').find('.has-error').remove();
        this.currentElements.parents('.form-group:first').removeClass('has-error');

        $.each(list, function(index, error) 
        {
            var ee = $(error.element);
            var eep = ee.parents('label:first').length ? ee.parents('label:first') : ee.parents('div:first');

            ee.parents('.form-group:first').addClass('has-error');
            eep.find('.has-error').remove();
            eep.append('<p class="has-error help-block">' + error.message + '</p>');
        });
    }
});

$(function()
{
    $("#register_form").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12
            },
            email_address: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your password must be no more than 12 characters long"
            },
            email_address: {
                required: "Please provide an email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var uri = "/register/process";
            $.post(uri, $( "#register_form" ).serialize(), function(output)
            {
                if (output.status == "notice")
                {
                    /*
                    notyfy({
                        text: output.message,
                        type: 'alert',
                        layout: 'center',
                        closeWith: ['click']
                    });
                    */                    
                }
                else if(output.status == "error")
                {
                    // Show errors even if jQuery validation missed some from server side validation.  

                    notyfy({
                        text: output.message,
                        type: 'error',
                        layout: 'center',
                        closeWith: ['click']
                    });
                }
                else if(output.status == "success")
                {   
                    // Works
                    notyfy({
                        text: output.message,
                        type: 'success',
                        layout: 'center',
                        closeWith: ['click']
                    });  
                }
                else
                {
                    /*
                    notyfy({
                        text: output.message,
                        type: 'warning',
                        layout: 'center',
                        closeWith: ['click']
                    });
                    */
                }
            }, 'json');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I've been attempting to understand from documentation from the jquery validation plugin about what to do and think I'm overlooking something. Does anybody know or have any suggestions? Any comments will be accepted.

Comment: So it's still a bit unclear... you want to use a client-side validation plugin to display server-side validation errors?

Comment: That is correct. I didn't know if I can use the showErrors function from JS.

Comment: `showErrors` is a callback function of the plugin.  There's no method provided for you to call it externally.  However, I think you need to reconsider your whole approach.  Server-side and client-side validation are two completely different things... client-side validation is for a better user experience and server-side validation protects your database.  So it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to use a client-side validation plugin simply to show server-side errors.  You might as well just stick with server-side validation and use ajax to dynamically place the messages on your page.

Comment: Well I currently use client side validation and ALSO have server side validation going on in my backend. Reason I have both is just in case there's some hacking going on and I have a backend to be another layer of protection and when I get the results back if there's validation errors in the backend then I can display those in such a way that its the same as the client side does with the plugin. I understand they are different.

Comment: Otherwise my idea would be to get the array of validation errors that are reported from the backend and match the form field with which field was hte error and do css to get it to show the errors the same way.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having both client and server side validations.  Typically, the client side validation occurs without reloading the page.  This is why people use client-side validation in the first place, to avoid calling the server and reloading the page every time there's an error.  Since most people have JavaScript enabled and will only see the client-side validation, your server-side validation is only used to protect yourself from mischief.  If the client-side validation is functioning properly, the user will never see anything from the server-side validation.

Comment: My point is that if you want to map the server-side errors to the form, then skip client-side validation entirely... I don't see the point.  Using some ajax will prevent you from having to reload the page as much.

Comment: I'm just having a hard time understanding why I would want to skip it if I want to do both front end validation and backend validation.